# How to apply non-default palette to multiple pieces bar graph in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I am really confused by the documentation and examples in some bar plot that I am doing in R+ggplot2.
I have this whatsapp data that needs to be plotted in bars, by the hour of day and colored by author. The default palette does the right thing in this code:

```
- datos2 %>%
        mutate(hour = hour(time)) %>%
        count(author,hour) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = n, fill=author)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        scale_fill_viridis_b()+   
        ylab("") + xlab("Mensajes por hora") +
        ggtitle(title)+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23)
```

[image: the right idea, horrible colors]

but the default palette is absolutely unreadable.
So I tried many other palettes and none work.
My data has 20 "authors", then, the RColorBrewer palette complains that it they have less colors than needed and show me a graph where most labels get gray colored. No use.
So I tried the viridis palettes, and they all show errors.
If I try

```
....
        ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = n, fill=author)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        scale_fill_viridis_b()+   
        ylab("") + xlab("Mensajes por hora") +
        ggtitle(title)+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23)
```

I get this error

```
Error in `train()`:
! Binned scales only support continuous data
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If I add the `discrete=TRUE` to the   `scale_fill_viridis_b()`
function, then I get a blank graph and the previous error, plus an "unused option" warning.

Comment: Try the `hues` package (available on CRAN), you can call `scale_fill_iwanthue` for as many colors as you need, and they come out very pretty. You can also tinker with parameters to get different color spaces. It's based on a website that you can play with outside of R: [https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/](https://medialab.github.io/iwanthue/)

Comment: The issue with the palettes in RColorBrewer is that they do not have enough colors compared to the number of authors in your data.  You can see the palettes if you do `library(RColorBrewer)` followed by `display.brewer.all()`. If you remove your `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23)` statement, what do you get? Also, what do you get if you use `scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE)`?

Comment: Let see David. Removing both things, I get `
Error in `train()`:
! Binned scales only support continuous data
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Removing only the "scale" thing, I get `Error in binned_scale(aesthetics, "viridis_b", pal, na.value = na.value,  : 
  unused argument (discrete = TRUE)` and, when calling the graph, I get the same error as before.

Comment: Leaving the "scale" and removing the `discrete=TRUE` I get again the same error of `Error in train() ...`